# Samba inconsistent performance

Tags: linux, windows, samba

i have migrated a home (file) server from windows 10 to linux Debian Jessie. I've installed samba from Debian's repo and setup a basic public share. Now the problem: if i copy a file from that public directory to a windows machine (with windows 10) the average speed is about 120MB/s so eveything is ok, but if i copy the same file to a linux machine i get only 500KB/s, very strange. Note:  there aren't problem if i send files to that share both from windows and linux, so the problem is only when i copy some files from the file server to a linux client. I've tried to use different linux distribution as client like Arch and also openELEC  or an android phone just for testing: they have the same problem.
Thank you very much for your help this is my samba config (as you can see is near the original after installation) 
[Link to configuration](http://pastebin.com/kdKDC9Dj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've found a solution after spending hours: first it's not a samba problem my configuration is ok. It's a bug of kernel's driver about the TSO corruption of my atl1e card Disabling TSO resolves every problem. I've also send a bug report to linux developers.